# BLE peripheral Connect/Disconnect callback

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

`BluetoothGattCallback` equivalent in iOS.

I'm developing a `BLE` App for `iOS` and `Android` as well.

In `Android`, in `connectGatt()` method one of the parameters is a callback 
"`BluetoothGattCallback`" witch listen for the connection state change and services discovered.

For example, when the user switch off the `BLE` device, the callback is called and i get the "`BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED`" (in `iOS` i get the `didDisconnectPeripheral`)

And when the user switch on the `BLE` Device again, in `Android` i get the "`BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED`".

Unfortunately, in `iOS` i can't find a callBack which announce me the device was on again.

Maybe i'm missing something here.

How can i know that the user switched on the device, for reconnecting to it.

Comment: When you get a disconnection event you need to issue a new `connect` request.  When the connection is made you will get a call to your `didConnect` delegate method.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks a lot. it's working like a charm.